# type check with typescript interface inheritance

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface

I have an interface and two interfaces that extend it:

```js
interface Layer {
    name: string;
    pretty_name: string;
}

interface SubLayer extends Layer{
    url: string;
}

interface AnotherLayer extends Layer{
    file: string;
}
```

Then I a service I have function that handles any `Layer` argument, and then needs to distinguish between the sub-interfaces and call the correct functions according:

```js
class LayerDataService {

    static getLayer(layer: Layer) {
        if (......) {
            return LayerDataService.getSubLayer(layer as SubLayer );
        }
        else if (......) {
            return LayerDataService.getAnotherLayer(layer as AnotherLayer);
        }
    }

    static getAnotherLayer (layer: AnotherLayer) {

    }
    static getSubLayer(layer: SubLayer) {

    }
}
```

So on the ..... there I want to distinguish between layers which implement `SubLayer` and layers implementing `AnotherLayer`.

So I know I can't use instanceof, because they aren't classes, they're objects implementing interfaces. But is there a way that doesn't involve manually checking each-and-every attribute manually like I can do in type guards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since interfaces are erased at compile time, there's no runtime information about them, hence no `instanceof`. The only solution I can think of is to invert the dependency, so it's the layer that decides how it's called...

```js
class LayerDataService {
    static getLayer(layer: Layer) {
        layer.get(this);
    }
}

interface Layer {
    name: string;
    pretty_name: string;
    
    get(service: LayerDataService): void;
}

interface SubLayer extends Layer{
    url: string;
}

interface AnotherLayer extends Layer{
    file: string;
}
```

This way each implementation is responsible for calling the relevant function on the `LayerDataService`, which admittedly adds overhead. I'm not entirely sure whether this would work in your case, but I thought worth mentioning.

Comment: Yeah that could work. I went another way and that is to convert my interfaces into classes instead. I'll post the answer to that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but you can possibly use type guard function I think.

```js
function (layer: unknown): layer is AnotherLayer {
   return !!layer.file;
}
```

Do the same for `SubLayer`, then you can use it as standard function but inside the parenthesis you will have it strongly typed as the specified type.

Comment: That would require me to check every property of the interface manually in the guard, which seems a bit redundant since I already defined the interface itself. If I change my interface, I also need to change it twice, once in the interface definition and once in the type guard. So basically duplicating the interface definition. I was hoping there is a better way. Similar to `instanceof`.